# Python pydantic range validation

Tags: python, pydantic

I have the next model:

```
class UserPreference(BaseModel):
    smoking: Optional[int] = Field(..., ge=0, le=4, description="How mach user = smoking", example=2)
    alcohol: Optional[int] = Field(..., ge=0, le=4, description="How mach user = alcohol", example=2)
    kids: Optional[int] = Field(..., ge=0, le=4, description="How many kids user has", example=2)
    height: Optional[int] = Field(..., ge=50, le=250, description="Height of the user", example=180)
    weight: Optional[int] = Field(..., ge=20, le=200, description="weight of the user", example=80)
    sport: Optional[int] = Field(..., ge=0, le=4, description="How mach user = sport", example=2)

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

And I want to create a new class from the class above.
Each field must be a list of 2 items (low boundary and high boundary of fields above)

A rough solution:

```
class UserSearchPreference(BaseModel):
    low_smoking: Optional[int] = Field(..., ge=0, le=4, description="How mach user = smoking", example=2)
    high_smoking: Optional[int] = Field(..., ge=0, le=4, description="How mach user = smoking", example=2)
    low_alcohol: Optional[int] = Field(..., ge=0, le=4, description="How mach user = alcohol", example=2)
    high_alcohol: Optional[int] = Field(..., ge=0, le=4, description="How mach user = alcohol", example=2)
    low_kids: Optional[int] = Field(..., ge=0, le=4, description="How many kids user has", example=2)
    high_kids: Optional[int] = Field(..., ge=0, le=4, description="How many kids user has", example=2)
    low_height: Optional[int] = Field(..., ge=50, le=250, description="Height of the user", example=180)
    high_height: Optional[int] = Field(..., ge=50, le=250, description="Height of the user", example=180)
    low_weight: Optional[int] = Field(..., ge=20, le=200, description="weight of the user", example=80)
    high_weight: Optional[int] = Field(..., ge=20, le=200, description="weight of the user", example=80)
    low_sport: Optional[int] = Field(..., ge=0, le=4, description="How mach user = sport", example=2)
    high_sport: Optional[int] = Field(..., ge=0, le=4, description="How mach user = sport", example=2)
```

How I can implement it?

P.S. Additionally it's preferable to check that `low_boundary < high_boundary` (`list[0] < list[-1]`)

Answer (score 3):

For your first requirement i.e. *Each field must be a list of 2 items (low boundary and high boundary of fields above)*, you can use something like this.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class UserSearchPreference(BaseModel):
    low_smoking: list[int] = Field(..., ge=0, le=4, min_items=2, max_items=2,
                                   description="How mach user = smoking",
                                   example=[2, 3])
```

As for the second requirement, you can use a [custom validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/) or a [root validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/#root-validators) for multiple fields after parsing.